# Concurrency Future syntax in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, completable-future

I use simple java code for Future:

```
Future<Integer> futureTask = executor.submit(() -> {
    System.out.println("I'm Callable task.");
    return 1 + 1;
});
```

when I paste it to kotlin class it transforms to :

```
val futureTask = executor.submit {
    println("I'm Callable task.")
    1 + 1
}
```

but when I try to get a value as in Java class I`m got null instead number

```
val integ = futureTask.get()
```

when I write return as in java code my ide warns that return is not allowed here.

Full kotlin code is next:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
   val futureTask = executor.submit {
       println("I'm Callable task.")
       1 + 1
   }

   println(futureTask.get())
   executor.shutdown() }
```

Output:

```
I'm Callable task.
null
```

What is a right syntax for `Future`?

Comment: That should be the correct syntax and you shouldn't get null. Please try to make your example complete and verifiable: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because there are two `submit` methods in `ExecutorService` and the wrong one is used.

```java
<T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task);

Future<?> submit(Runnable task);
```

Your lambda function is translated to a Runnable instead of Callable.
You can workaround this as following:

```kotlin
val futureTask = executor.submit(Callable {
    println("I'm Callable task.")
    1 + 1
})
```